# What exactly contains the word vector of Word2Vec (or generally of word embeddings, but we can stay with Word2Vec)

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, word2vec

Is is possible to explain it? I have a property that I always need to understand everything. I read somewhere that it is the "context" or the content of hidden neural layer (its weights), but still is it possible to sufficiently explain what exactly is in the vector of Word2Vec?

Is it really some random weights in it nothing more, no smart intention?

Btw I was now checking some basic Neural network and I noticed that in the simplest case is mapped one input to one neuron, meaning one neuron = one weight, but on further diagram i noticed some "fully connection" that all inputs are mapped to all neurons, then it seems one neuron = N weights where N is the number of inputs to it.

But I wonder if Word2vec vector would be really just the hidden layer (the weights) how it can be just let's say 100 weights in case of fully connected inputs, where as I say 1 neuron is more than 1 weight.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [what does the vector of a word in word2vec represents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27032517/what-does-the-vector-of-a-word-in-word2vec-represents)